# How to specify sql dialect when creating spark dataframe from JDBC?

Tags: apache-spark, jdbc, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-2.0, vitess

I'm having an issue reading data via custom JDBC with Spark. How would I go about about overriding the sql dialect inferred via jdbc url?

The database in question is vitess (https://github.com/youtube/vitess) which runs a mysql variant, so I want to specify a mysql dialect. 
The jdbc url begins with jdbc:vitess/

Otherwise the DataFrameReader is inferring a default dialect which uses """ as a quote identifier. As a result, queries via spark.read.jdbc get sent as

> Select 'id', 'col2', col3', 'etc' from table

which selects the string representations instead of the column values
instead of

> Select id, col2, col3, etc from table

Answer (score 8):

Maybe it's too late. But answer will be next:

Create your custom dialect, as I did for ClickHouse database(my jdbc connection url looks like this jdbc:clickhouse://localhost:8123)

```
 private object ClickHouseDialect extends JdbcDialect {
    //override here quoting logic as you wish
    override def quoteIdentifier(colName: String): String = colName

    override def canHandle(url: String): Boolean = url.startsWith("jdbc:clickhouse")
  }
```

And register it somewhere in your code, like this:

```
JdbcDialects.registerDialect(ClickHouseDialect)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this.

```
val jdbcDF = spark.read
  .format("jdbc")
  .option("url", "jdbc:postgresql:dbserver")
  .option("dbtable", "schema.tablename")
  .option("user", "username")
  .option("password", "password")
  .load()
```

For more info check [this](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#jdbc-to-other-databases)

You can also specify in this way.

```
val connectionProperties = new Properties()
    connectionProperties.put("user", "username")
    connectionProperties.put("password", "password")
    val jdbcDF2 = spark.read
      .jdbc("jdbc:postgresql:dbserver", "schema.tablename", connectionProperties)
```

Comment: What would be the best way to specify a SQL Dialect without using the jdbc url? The issue is that I am using a custom jdbc with url prefix "jdbc:vitess". The jdbc needs a url specified as "jdbc:vitess" but I want spark to interpret the connection as a MySQL dialect.