# ClickHouse Spark Connector - Scala Dependancy

Tags: scala, apache-spark, sbt, sbt-assembly, clickhouse

I am using https://github.com/DmitryBe/clickhouse-spark-connector

I create my jar with sbt assembly after I cloned the repo and then I add my import statements.

```
import io.clickhouse.ext.ClickhouseConnectionFactory
import io.clickhouse.ext.spark.ClickhouseSparkExt._
```

object clickhouse is not a member of package spark.jobserver.io

I can see that these paths exist and they are added as dependencies the same way I have added all the others. I have cleaned and rebuilt etc but it has made no difference. I am using scala-ide(eclipse).

Comment: Try to invalidate cache and restart IDE. That should work I guess

Comment: I cant find how to clear the cache in scala ide - I have run clean and restarted it several times and it hasn't helped.

Comment: try this http://eclipsesource.com/blogs/2012/08/31/reloading-your-p2-cache/

Comment: I'm pretty sure the module is just broken. I imported all the classes manually and I can't get one of the dependencies to resolve no matter what I do. Thank you for your help. I also loaded up intellij and tried it there to make sure it wasn't a caching issue.

Comment: If you update your question with your requirements, sample codes, then I including others would be helping you quickly

Answer (score 0):

You can try using https://github.com/yandex/clickhouse-jdbc

Here is a snippet which you can use to write dataframe into Clickhouse using your own dialect. `ClickhouseDialect` is a class which extends `JdbcDialects`. You can create your dialect and register it using `JdbcDialects.registerDialect(clickhouse)`

```
def write(data: DataFrame, jdbcUrl: String, tableName: String): Unit = {

    val clickhouse = new ClickhouseDialect()

    JdbcDialects.registerDialect(clickhouse)

    val props = new java.util.Properties()
    props.put("driver", "ru.yandex.clickhouse.ClickHouseDriver")
    props.put("connection", jdbcUrl)

    val repartionedData = data.repartition(100)

    repartionedData.write
      .mode(SaveMode.Append)
      .jdbc(jdbcUrl, tableName, props)

    JdbcDialects.unregisterDialect(clickhouse)

}
```

You can check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45743348/6148927) to create your own dialect. You might have to override `canHandle`, `getJDBCType`, `getCatalystType` methods of  `JdbcDialects` for your usage.